# Exist another method to solve the problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

We have $x_1,\:x_2,\:x_3\:\in \:\mathbb{C},\:\:f=x^3+x^2+mx+m,\:m\in \mathbb{R}$.
We need to find $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x_1|=|x_2|=|x_3|$.

Here is what I tried: $f=x^3+x^2+mx+m=(x^2+m)(x+1)$, so one of root is:

$x=-1$, and if we put the condition from statement it means $|x_1|=|x_2|=|-1|=1$.
From Vieta's formula, for cubic polynomial: $x_1x_2x_3=-m$.
Therefore:

> for $x_3=-1$ we'll obtain $m=-x_1x_2x_3=x_1x_2=1$
>
> for $x_3=1$ we'll obtain $m=-x_1x_2x_3=-1$

I was wrong somewhere? Exist another method to solve the problem?

Comment: what about $m = -1?$  in fact what about $m = e^{it}, t \in R?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is the good one, nevertheless I do not quite understand how you go from Vieta's formula to the other statement.

As you have remarked $f(-1)=0$ whatever $m$ might be so you will always have $x_3=-1$ (up to renumerotation of the roots). Now this impose $|x_1|=|x_2|=|x_3|=1$ but because :

$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x+1)=f(x)=(x^2+m)(x+1) $$

One must have :

$$x^2-(x_1+x_2)x+x_1x_2=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=x^2+m $$

Hence one has :

$$x_1+x_2=0\text{ and } x_1x_2=m $$

That is :

$$x_1=-x_2\text{ and } -x_1^2=m $$

Now I claim that $|x_1|=1$ if and only if $|m|=1$. And any choice of $m$ with $|m|=1$ will give you solutions :

$$m=1\Leftrightarrow x_1^2=-1\Leftrightarrow (x_1,x_2)=(i,-i)\text{ or }(-i,i) $$

$$m=-1\Leftrightarrow x_1^2=1\Leftrightarrow (x_1,x_2)=(1,-1)\text{ or }(-1,1) $$

Hence to fullfill those conditions one must have $m=\pm 1$ and any choice of $m\in\{\pm1\}$ allows you to construct a triplet solution.

Comment: I don't understand the final:  $|x_1|=1$ if and only if $|y|=1$ if and only if $|m|=1$ ... what did you led to say it?

Comment: from where $|m|=1$ ?

Comment: This is because of the equations I have written on the line above (actually $y$ is defined to be $x_1$)  and $|m|=|-y^2|=|y|^2$.

Comment: what's happening with this site.. no longer is as it was before... with many answers and with full vote up for a good answer or question...

Comment: is really necessary a substitution in this case? I think is the same case if we say $|x_2|=1$ if and only if $|m|=|-x_2^2|=1$

Comment: You are right, the $y$ is useless.